# How exclude string part from main string that has in array by javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have string that exist in array as follow

```
getid Array [
  "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2",
]
```

I want to exclude this part `E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe2` from that ,

actually `E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe2` this is user.uid .
this is two user id combine id  `"E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2"`
this combine id exist in arrays.
so many combine id will has in this array.
I want to exclude user.uid `E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe2` from all combine id .
if exclude user.uid , there will be remain one id part in this array.
I want to get this remain part of id value to use.

```
let userid = E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe2
let combineId = ["E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2","E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lh5bHrzCSvI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2","E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2"]

// this is value what i want
let remainIdinArray = ["6Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2","6Lh5bHrzCSvI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2","6Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2"]
```

how can do that.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You can just loop over and [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the `userId` with `''` (empty string) and you will get what you are expecting

```js
let userid = "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe2";
let combineId = [
  "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2",
  "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lh5bHrzCSvI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2",
  "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2",
];

const result = combineId.map((id) => id.replace(userid, ""));
console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can also use [`slice`](http://v), [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to get the desired result as:

```js
let userid = "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe2";
let combineId = [
  "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2",
  "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lh5bHrzCSvI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2",
  "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2",
];

const result = combineId.map((id) => id.slice(id.indexOf(userid) + userid.length));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: this output get with user.uid, I want value output is not user.uid. how can edit it.your code output get with user.uid,```getid Array [
  "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2",
]
Array [
  "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe2",
]```

Comment: @micheal what are you trying to say. Please be specific and clear...

Comment: sorry ,Your answer is correct.My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map and the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)!

```
    let userid = "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe2";
    let combineId = [
      "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2",
      "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lh5bHrzCSvI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2",
      "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2"
    ];
    
    let remainIdinArray = combineId.map((id) => id.slice(-userid.length));
    
    console.log(remainIdinArray);
```

Comment: this is correct answer. thanks bro

Comment: you're welcome and good luck